# Error when building FLTK: Configure could not find required X11 libraries

Tags: c++, msys2, fltk

I am having trouble getting FLTK set up. I am currently using windows and trying to built it with msys2. Whenever I try to configure it with ./configure I get this error:

```
configure: error: Configure could not find required X11 libraries, aborting.
```

Here is the full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/raw/YeA72wYr

I tried redownloading FLTK without success.

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Are you reading and following the [windows readme](https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/master/README.Windows.txt)? It can help others help you if you give this kind of context/info. For example, here's my question I wouldn't need to ask otherwise: have you run `autoconf` yet? Could also help if you share how/where you download from, and what version of FLTK you're using.

Comment: I am using fltk-1.3.8. I am following the windows section of this page: https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/intro.html, as well as the windows readme which both give similar steps. I downloaded fltk from here: https://www.fltk.org/software.php

Comment: Thank you adding the build flag: --build=mingw32 fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/deech/fltkhs/issues/74), where jputcu could workaround the issue by passing `--build=mingw32` to the configure script.

You can read the rest of the GitHub issue to learn more, or subscribe to it follow discussion. Feel free to participate there.